# check if each string is bigger or smaller than a defined value

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to check if a given string is greater or smaller than a predefined value by using jquery. Whether true or false div.property_energy should be marked with a certain class.

Updated: My code isn't working as expected. No matter how big or small the string is, 'div.property_energy' is always marked as yellow.

Here's the code:

```
$('.property_energy').each(function () {
        var n = parseInt(this.value);
        if(n < 151){
            $(this).addClass("green");
        }
        else if (n > 300) {
            $(this).addClass("red");
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass("yellow");
        }
    });
```

Comment: And your quesiton is?

Comment: Did you look at `n`? My guess: it's `NaN` because `this.value` is either undefined or not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading in jquery docs more precisely i found the answer by myself.

```
    $('.property_energy').each(function () {
    var n = $(this).text();
    if($.isNumeric(n) && n < 151) {
        $(this).addClass("green");
        alert("smaller than 151");
    }
    else if ($.isNumeric(n) && n > 300) {
        $(this).addClass("red");
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass("yellow");
    }
});
```

tanks to Johannes H. your comment got me on the right way.